# Auto Increment in hibernate using oracle

Tags: java, hibernate, primary-key

I am new to hibernate and I want to insert primary number in my table for unique identification. I am using Oracle as my database so do I need to create sequence in oracle to get auto increment generation number ?

I am using below code but it is not working. I have not created any sequence yet.

```
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id" )
 @GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
```

I have used `AUTO`, `SEQUENCE` and `IDENTITY` but nothing works for me.

Comment: kindly recheck GenerationType.AUTO

Comment: You should really only need to have `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue`, as the default for generated is auto increment.

Comment: What does it mean "nothing works"...`AUTO` will do it for you.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single#mapping-declaration-id-generator

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar brother i have already tried with it and it gives me this error."Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value"

Comment: @PratikJoshi I can not determine the root cause from content provided in que, however you can check answer.

Answer (score 8):

this is one way of using Oracle sequence in a JPA mapped entity:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQUENCE_NAME")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQUENCE_NAME", sequenceName = "SEQUENCE_NAME", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
```

In this way your persist() method will ask for the next value of the sequence in order to use it as ID for your entry.

Comment: This causes the following error "sometimes" 
> error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; constraint [SYSTEM.SYS_C0010941]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: error performing isolated work

Answer (score 1):

You can ue this `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id" )
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `GenerationType.TABLE` option, ID value will be filled with the column of other table.

If you are using `strategy=GenerationType.TABLE` you will require to mention the Table from where your ID will be filled.

For example,

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="course")
@TableGenerator(
    name="course",
    table="GENERATOR_TABLE",
    pkColumnName = "key",
    valueColumnName = "next",
    pkColumnValue="course",
    allocationSize=30
)
```

And for other option, you can use `GenerationType.AUTO` option, and let hibernate decide which option to choose according to databse.

```
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id" )
 @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

And make sure that you properly configured `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.